# Bash: Flip strings to the other side of the delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, grep, formatting

Basically, I have a file formatted like

```
ABC:123
```

And I would like to flip the strings around the delimiter, so it would look like this

```
123:ABC
```

I would prefer to do this with bash/linux tools.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

That's reasonably easy with internal `bash` commands, assuming two fields, as per the following transcript:

```
pax:~$ x='abc:123'
pax:~$ echo "${x#*:}:${x%:*}"
123:abc
```

The first substitution `${x#*:}` removes everything from the start up to the colon. The second, `${x%:*}`, removes everything from the colon to the end.

Then you just re-join them with the colon in-between.

It doesn't matter for your *particular* data but `%` and `#` use the shortest possible pattern. The `%%` and `##` variants will give you the longest possible pattern (greedy).

---

As an aside, this is ideal if you doing it for one string at a time since you don't need to kick up an external process to do the work for you. But, if you're processing an entire file, there are better ways to do it, such as with `awk`:

```
pax:~$ printf "abc:123\ndef:456\nghi:789\n" | awk -F: '{print $2 FS $1}'
123:abc
456:def
789:ghi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh -x

var1=$(echo -e 'ABC:123' | cut -d':' -f1) 
var2=$(echo -e 'ABC:123' | cut -d':' -f2)
echo -e "${var2}":"${var1}"
```

I use cut to split the string into two parts, and store both of those parts as variables.

From there, it's possible to use echo to re-arrange the variables as you see fit.

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`.

```
sed -E 's/(.*):(.*)/\2:\1/' file.txt
```

Using `paste` and `cut` with process substitution.

```
paste -d: <(cut -d : -f2 file.txt) <(cut -d : -f1 file.txt)
```

A slower/slowest shell solution on large set of data/files.

```
while IFS=: read -r left rigth; do printf '%s:%s\n' "$rigth" "$left"; done < file.txt
```